# How to schedule a job in apache-flink

Tags: apache-flink

I want to write a task that is triggered by apache flink after every 24 hours and then processed by flink. What is the possible way to do this? Does flink provide any job scheduling functionality?

Answer (score 5):

Apache Flink is not a job scheduler but an event processing engine which is a different paradigm, as Flink jobs are supposed to run continuously instead of being triggered by a schedule.

That said, you could achieve the functionality by simply using an off the shelve scheduler (i.e. cron) who is scheduled to start a job on your Flink cluster and then stop it after you receive some sort of notification that the job was done (i.e. through a Kafka topic) or simply use a timeout after which you would assume that the job is finished and you can stop the job. But again, especially because Flink is not designed for this kind of use cases, you would most certainly run into edge cases which Flink does not support.

Alternatively you can simply use a 24 hour tumbling window and run your task in the corresponding trigger function. See https://flink.apache.org/news/2015/12/04/Introducing-windows.html for details on that matter.